# Using Robot framework for Java GUI

Tags: python, swing, robotframework, ui-automation, robotframework-ide

I am new to Robotframework as well as to Python. I got to do the Functional Testing of the Java application(not a single jar file, but it is an installer file) and even i got to know that there is SwingLibrary for doing that.
Now my question is

- What all the tools do I need to have apart form Robotframework, RIDE
- Will it be the Java coding or the Python scripts?
- How to connect my application to the test framework

and please post any documentations for learning because i went through [this link](http://robotframework.org/SwingLibrary/SwingLibrary-1.9.2.html) , but i didn't understand where to deploy this thing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Other than Ride, you can use Eclipse IDE. Install java and set environmental variables for that along with Eclipse IDE on your
   machine. To create your own robot framework you need to add a plugin
   called "RED" in your eclipse IDE.
2. There will be libraries available for some actions. If you want to create your own then you can write your test scripts using python or Java with robot framework. Every method name would be your keyword.
3. Once you create your own robot project, you can import the libraries that you want into red.XML which you will find in your
       robot project.

Let me know if you have any queries..

Comment: Is it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525558/how-to-import-java-class-to-robot-framework-like-library)?